# Google Play throwing error code -505 when installing custom app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

We are distributing an app via Google Play. Currently, there are two versions of the app in beta:

- Production - com.domain.standard - Points to the production server.
- Development - com.domain.evv - Points to the development server.

We are finding that users can only have one version installed on their phone at a time. For example:

- I attempt to install the development version via Google Play. All is good.
- I attempt to install the production version via Google Play. I get error code "-505".
- I uninstall the development version.
- I attempt to install the production version via Google Play. All is good.

I've done all I can to rule out device-specific causes; we are seeing this on multiple devices. To my knowledge, there is no device currently running both versions.

---

For reference, the full error is:

> "APP NAME" can't be installed. Try again, and if the problem continues, get help troubleshooting. (Error code: -505)

We have gone through all the troubleshooting tips and none appear to remedy the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Error code -505 usually means a signature mismatch between APK which is already on device and the one being installed.

However, if the package names are different, this can't be the issue. My guess would be PackageManager is giving a [STATUS_FAILURE_CONFLICT](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=2n-OWp-9D4z0gQb9jZHYAQ&q=site%3Aandroid.googlesource.com+%22STATUS_FAILURE_CONFLICT%22+java&oq=site%3Aandroid.googlesource.com+%22STATUS_FAILURE_CONFLICT%22+java) - PackageManager actually uses [this code for lots of things](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r4/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#5541).

- Already exists (obviously), but also
- `INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE`
- `INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE`
- `INSTALL_FAILED_REPLACE_COULDNT_DELETE`
- `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER`
- `INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION`

I don't know exactly what all of these mean (but I could carry on looking in the source code to find out), but is it possible one of them applies to your APK? My top guess would be [this code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F#8351), I wonder if your debug package and your release package have conflicting providers?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure any other versions / development versions are uninstalled from the phone for All Users. Do this by going into Settings -> Apps and making sure the app is uninstalled for all users.

If you delete the app from the home screen, you will likely delete it only for the current user.